# Cake Session Terminating too quickly

Tags: php, iphone, cakephp, session-cookies, session-timeout

I'm making an iphone app that communicates with a CakePHP site. On the app & site the user logs in and a session is generated. On the site the session persists but it does not on the app. It seems to expire after about an hour between requests.

I edited Cake's core config file to use CAKEPHP for Session.cookie, set the Session.timeout to be a very big number (e.g. 1036800) and finally Security.level to 'low'.

The iPhone app displays the token I'm sending up to Cake and the token Cake is expecting for the user, unfortunately the token its expecting is always empty/deleted.

When testing I set the Session.timeout value to be 1 (5 minutes) and 2 (ten minutes) and the session expired at the correct times, but setting it to a large number just seems to make it expire at about an hour :(

any ideas would be great :D

Comment: Why do you need sessions that live more than hour?

Comment: Hey Zerkms, Its a requirement of the project that the sessions live a long time

Comment: Hey Zerkms, they're a few reasons for it. Do you know a solution to this issue? Shouldn't the settings I have provided make the session last more than an hour?

Comment: lol, ok you win Zerkms, I actually laughed at that last comment, well played :D

Comment: you will be surprised but in 99% cases requirement of long sessions is pointless. But you can continue laughing

Comment: Hey Zerkms, the user data is stored in the session. The app is typically used for a few hours and when it makes a the call to the server to update some settings with the data collected in the past few hours it gets the timeout issue. I'm afraid I did not create the Server application so I'm stuck with having to find a solution to this issue :( The application depends upon the server holding the session for a long time, even weeks. I'm thinking it might be server session garbage collection or the settings in the ini file being preferred by the server?

Comment: if user goes through pages - then session will live indefinitely. btw, how many vhosts are on your server? If more than one - then move your app session files to another directory.

Comment: Hi Zerkms, I could be wrong but I do not think that the pages logic is not applicable to this scenario with communication between the iPhone app and the Cake App. That may be a reason as to the session expiration. The Cake app lives on a shared server with two other sites. I changed the session files to another directory so hopefully in an hours time the session will still be alive :D Sorry for the short answers before, I thought you were joking with me, my mistake, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP might cleanup the session after a set amount of time. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime

Comment: exactly - you need to (independendly from ANY settings in cake) set this value up.